Three.js: How to prevent flickering, which occurs when page restarts. (White flashing)
On my discover flickering occurs when page “off”. Effect act during 1-2ms in canvas. Moreover this problem may occur or not occur in any canvas blocks on page.
I tested more variants of solution this problem: wrote simple version of code, hided HTML until scene rendering, changed background on canvas and parents blocks, but nothing work.
I also tested more simple version with scene from tutorial three.js, but scene also flickering.
Maybe somebody encounter with this problem, give me advice please! 
Attach video with problem in thread
/*Styles*/
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const BlockForModel = styled.div`
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  opacity: 0;
`

/*React*/
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/*Created components*/
import {CreateScene} from "@ui/functions/tests/InitialTest";

/*Styles*/
import * as S from './styles/styles';



const ModelStandard = () => {
    const modelCanvas = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (modelCanvas.current){
            CreateScene(modelCanvas.current)
        }
    }, )

    return (
        <S.BlockForModel ref={modelCanvas}></S.BlockForModel>
    );
};

export default ModelStandard;

import * as THREE from 'three';


export function CreateScene(block){
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, block.offsetWidth / block.offsetHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( block.offsetWidth, block.offsetHeight );
    block.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    block.style.opacity = "100%"
    renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
}

